# How do i reserve my new lines in Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question, is... better if i explained my app, which will lead to problem.. Basically i am making a forum application using angularjs and firebase.. So when a user posts a new topic, this appears:

[image]

As you can see there is new lines between the sentences.. in the topic. Now when i post that topic, and i come to see it, this is what i see:

[image]

You can see the new lines has been deleted.. In the coding part what i did when user submits new topic is just save it in a firebase:

```
$scope.submitNewTopic = function() {

            refService.ref().child("UserAuthInfo").child(currentAuth.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                $scope.userAvatar = snapshot.val().Image;
                $scope.userName = snapshot.val().Username;
                $scope.userEmail = snapshot.val().Email;

              var pushing = refService.ref().child("Topics").push({
                    Title: $scope.topic.title,
                    Value: $scope.topic.sentence,
                    DateCreated: Date.now(),
                    Username: $scope.userName,
                    Email: $scope.userEmail,
                    Avatar: $scope.userAvatar,
                    UID: currentAuth.uid,
                    Votes : 0
                })

                refService.ref().child("Topics").child(pushing.key()).update({
                    pushKey : pushing.key()
                })
            })
            $mdDialog.hide();
        }
```

I dont understand why its deleting the new lines, very confusing.. i had the newlines when the user was typing in his post, but as i put in firebase it just deleted them.. How do i keep new lines.. Thankyou for reading

Comment: That is not a duplicate lol @SimonC

Comment: No? You are both trying to preserve whitespace characters such as new lines in firebase. The very first live of the question is "I'd like a user to be able to type several paragraphs as a firebase input and have the newlines/returns/enter preserved for formatting purposes."

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/gipakakeve/edit?html,js,output. Type some text with new lines, hit Save, then hit Load.

Comment: Yea sorry @FrankvanPuffelen . .this is a dupe.. I have another question coming up.. but i have to go, so ill ask later